# Is it possible to change the baud rate using nrjavaserial-5.2.1 library without losing serial communication?

Tags: serial-port, serial-communication, rxtx

After altering the baud rate, serial communication no longer works using nrjavaserial-5.2.1 library

I'm attempting to contact with a chip card device using serial communication, which is linked to a reader via a serial port. The communication works fine when I use the initial baud rate 9600, but when I change the initial baud rate (9600 without closing the communication) of my serial port communication to a higher baud rate value (e.g. - 115200), the device closes the connection, despite the fact that the same device works fine with a higher baud rate using the jSerialComm library.
Please find the code snippet attached.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVANP.png)
Is the baud rate changing supported by the nrjavaserial library? I am event based serial communication.

Comment: The serial link configuration (i.e. baudrate, char size, parity and stop bits) has to be agreed upon and used by both ends of the link. When you have a working link, and then change a link parameter (such as the baudrate) on just one end of the link, then you have a non-working link to some degree (e.g. changing the number of stop bits is not as disruptive as changing the baudrate or char size). Your comparison and logic are too vague to make sense.